# Why the thread is locked?

Tags: android, multithreading, drawing, surfaceview, fingerprint

i download it [tutorial](https://github.com/droidcode/ThreadPaint) for finger paint. This app use surface view to implement painting.

However, I find that the drawing thread is locked and the system cannot unlock it when i close the app and reopen the app for four and five times.

Method call flow:
surfaceCreated -> start drawing thread -> surfaceChanged -> setSurfaceSize()

In the setSurfaceSize
synchronized (pThread) <---wait for drawing thread

However, sometime the thread is not unlocked by the system.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: from your description sounds like a deadlock may be, but without actual code really hard to see.

Comment: but, it sometimes work fine. Restart the app for four times. It cannot start app. I have no idea.

Comment: without actual code it is impossible to tell where the problem is